# Pandas: Read excel that has no column headers and data doesn't start at the first row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file which has data rows starting from the 28th row. The column headers aren't available.

```
df = xl.parse(sheetName, header=None, names=<list of column names>)
```

How do I specify that I need custom headers, and that my data starts at the 28th row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do that with:

```py
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
df = df.iloc[27:]
```